# simple javascript form onsubmit have 2 handles?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
<FORM name="form1" class="input" ACTION="<%WWW.CURRENTURL%>" METHOD=POST NAME=APPLFORM onsubmit="return Submitform(this) & return checkform(this);">
```

Can I use "&" to run 2 functions in ONSUBMIT in the FORM tag? will above work? sorry, my dev area limits me from running the code.

basically, Submitform(this) checks to make sure the disclaimer checkbox is check and
checkform(this) executes the captcha.

any advice, input, help is greatly appreciated.
thanks and happy 4th!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just run it as if it was JS code.

```
onsubmit="Submitform(this);return checkform(this);"
```

Comment: First return here prevents the second from firing. This doesn't work. Itf you removed the first return, you'd be in better shape.

Comment: @Ryan, yours worked and executed both handles, regardless of which order. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your code:

- It's `&&`, not `&`. The symbol `&` is a [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators), while `&&` is a logical and.
- You want to execute `SubmitForm()` only if `checkForm()` returns a true value, not the opposite.
- There are two `return` in your `onsubmit` attribute, which is invalid. There can only be one `return`.

You can fix your code like so

```
onsubmit="return (checkForm(this) && SubmitForm(this))"
```

This will execute `SubmitForm` only if `checkForm` returns a true value.

Comment: && isnt it or as well, submitForm(this) executed but not checkForm(this). I need both or one after the other, either way. need both to execute.

Comment: Then you need to use `checkForm(this); SubmitForm(this):`